# Animate GoogleMap to zoom and location in same animation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to animate to a zoom and a location at once, but it seems that is not possible.

If i do this, it only animates to the location:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16f));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
```

If i do this, it only animates to the zoom:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16f));
```

If I combine a `moveCamera` with a `animateCamera` for one of each, it works, but obviously only one has animation and the other not.

How can I animate both things, the zoom and the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally do it in two steps using a callback, if you find a better way please post it:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16f));
    }
});
```

UPDATE: thanks to @B__ for his better solution: `newLatLngZoom` function

Comment: See : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#public-static-cameraupdate-newlatlngzoom-latlng-latlng,-float-zoom